# EXCEL Passed Range To Function Is Always EMPTY

Tags: vba, excel

I am trying to create a User Defined Function in Excel 2007. The function is inside a VBA Module and accepts a single parameter, a Range object. The problem is that the parameter when received is always EMPTY. What am I missing?

```
Function ConcatenateCells(p_objConcatArea As Range) As String
    '******************************************
    ' Initialize Variables
    '******************************************
    Dim strReturnString As String

    '******************************************
    ' Process Each Cell In Range
    '******************************************
    strReturnString = ""
    For Each objCellValue In p_objConcateArea
        If (objCellValue <> "") Then
            If (strReturnString <> "") Then strReturnString = strReturnString & ", "
            strReturnString = strReturnString & objCellValue
        End If
    Next

    '******************************************
    ' Return Final Value
    '******************************************
    ConcatenateCells = strReturnString
End Function
```

In the Excel Sheet, inside the cell I wrote the following formula:

```
=ConcatenateCells(B22:B25)
```

I get **#VALUE!** as my result. I stepped through the code and found that the parameter (p_objConcateArea) is always EMPTY. Why can I not pass the range to my UDF?

Help!

-Ben

Comment: You should use Option Explicit``

Comment: ^^^^^ `p_objConcatArea` <> `p_objConcateArea`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is a "classical" case for the issues you have when not using Option Explicit. I corrected your typo

```
Option Explicit

Function ConcatenateCells(p_objConcatArea As Range) As String
    '******************************************
    ' Initialize Variables
    '******************************************
    Dim strReturnString As String
    Dim objCellValue
    'Dim p_objConcateArea

    '******************************************
    ' Process Each Cell In Range
    '******************************************
    strReturnString = ""
    For Each objCellValue In p_objConcatArea
        If (objCellValue <> "") Then
            If (strReturnString <> "") Then strReturnString = strReturnString & ", "
            strReturnString = strReturnString & objCellValue
        End If
    Next

    '******************************************
    ' Return Final Value
    '******************************************
    ConcatenateCells = strReturnString
End Function
```

Comment: OMG, a type, and a missing System Flag.  It's been so long since I used VBA, I forget how annoying it can be not to have intellisense. Thank you!!

Comment: _Tools ~ Options ~ Editor Tab ~ Require Variable Declaration_ to put `Option Explicit` on all new modules going forward.

Comment: Also always specify to pass parameters by value `ConcatenateCells(ByVal p_objConcatArea As Range)`. If you don't use `ByVal`, by default VBA passes the parameters by reference. This can give you some nasty and hard to find bugs. Here is [an example](http://www.excel-easy.com/vba/examples/byref-byval.html).